# Is it possible to identify if the numbers in a list in Python are consecutive?

Tags: python, variables

I'm trying to write a function that will determine if the numbers in a list are in consecutive order. My first thought was to see if I could get the program to check if the difference between one number and the one before it always equals one (e.g. position x - (x-1) == 1), but haven't found a way to define x as any given position, only specific positions.

This was my attempt so far:

```py
def is_consecutive(a_list):
    if a_list[x] - a_list[x-1] == 1:
        print("The list is consecutive.")
    else:
        print("The list is not consecutive.")

is_consecutive([1,2,3,4,5])
```

Is there a way to define x so that it references any and all positions in a list without putting in the specific position number?

Or am I overthinking things and there's a simpler solution altogether?

Comment: As a start you'll need to iterate over the list to derive that `x`. `for x in range(a_list):`

Comment: This will do the trick: `all( a_list[i] +1 == a_list[i+1] for i in range(len(a_list)) if i < len(a_list) - 1) `

Comment: "Is there a way to define x so that it references any and all positions in a list without putting in the specific position number?" You can write code that **tries all the possibilities**. There are many possible standard techniques for this; I will try to offer the relevant duplicate links.

Answer (score 2):

If all numbers are consecutive, the difference with their index will be the same for all of them. So all differences should be the same as the value of the first item (index 0):

```
def is_consecutive(L):
    return all(n-i==L[0] for i,n in enumerate(L))

print(is_consecutive([5,6,7])) # True
print(is_consecutive([7,9,8])) # False
print(is_consecutive([]))      # True
print(is_consecutive([1]))     # True
```

Or, You could let enumerate produce the expected values directly by giving it the first item as starting point:

```
def is_consecutive(L):
    return not L or all(n==i for i,n in enumerate(L,L[0]))
```

You can also use zip() to get each value and its successor in pairs:

```
def is_consecutive(L):
    return all(b-a==1 for a,b in zip(L,L[1:]))
```

Without any for-loop / comprehension, you could build a list from the range of values starting with the first element and ending with the last.  This generated list will be equal to your original list if all numbers in it are consecutive:

```
def is_consecutive(L):
    return not L or L == [*range(L[0],L[-1]+1)]
```

*The problem with this is that you could end up with an unreasonably large generated list (e.g. is_consecutive([5,1234567890])*

Also, without for-loops, you can use enumerate in such a way that the negative expected values are paired with the values in the list and use map to sum up those pairs.  If the items of the list are consecutive this should only produce zeros (False) results:

```
def is_consecutive(L):
    return not any(map(sum,enumerate(reversed(L),-sum(L[:1])-len(L)+1)))
```

Recursion, although it will only work for relatively small lists, would also be an option that doesn't involve for-loops:

```
def is_consecutive(L):
    return not L or L[0]+len(L)==L[-1]+1 and is_consecutive(L[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

```
def is_consecutive(array: list) -> bool:
    sorted_lst = sorted(array)
    for i in range(1, len(sorted_lst)):
        if sorted_lst[i] != sorted_lst[i - 1] + 1:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Please don't use a built-in like `list` for the name of a variable.

Comment: Absolutely, I was in a hurry and didn't think it through. Edited and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> but haven't found a way to define x as any given position, only specific positions

Well, that's what [loops](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) are for. Here is the simplest version

```py
def is_consecutive(a_list):
    is_consecutive = True
    for x in range(1, len(a_list)):
        if a_list[x] - a_list[x-1] != 1:
            is_consecutive = False
            break
    if is_consecutive:
        print("The list is consecutive.")
    else:
        print("The list is not consecutive.")
```

Python's [`zip` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip) makes it easier to write.

```py
def is_consecutive(a_list):
    is_consecutive = True
    for current, previous in zip(a_list[1:], a_list[:-1])):
        if current - previous != 1:
            is_consecutive = False
            break
```

or as one statement using [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#all) and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```py
    is_consecutive = all(current - previous == 1
                         for current, previous
                         in zip(a_list[1:], a_list[:-1]))
```

You can also be sneaky about it and simply compare the list to one that is consecutive since there is only exactly one for a given starting value. For large lists this wastes memory.

```py
    start = a_list[0]
    is_consecutive = a_list == list(range(start, start + len(a_list)))
```

Same approach but more efficient since it avoids building the entire list, instead using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#enumerate):

```py
    is_consecutive = all(entry == expected for expected, entry
                         in enumerate(a_list, start=a_list[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the iterator part where you go for each element. Without modifying too much your code:

```
def is_consecutive(a_list):
    for x in range(1, len(a_list): # iterate through each element of the list (starting at the second, index = 1)
        if a_list[x] - a_list[x-1] != 1: # evaluate your condition
            print("The list is not consecutive.")
            return # no need to work more
    print("The list is consecutive.") # if you arrived here, it means the list is consecutive
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a form of incrementation, make x = len(a_list), and then make the if statement a while loop

```
while a_list[x] - a_list[x-1] == 1:
```

so that it would run multiple times, and every time through the loop, call x -= 1 (to increment it down) and if x = 0, print("the list is consecutive.") and return, then write an if statement in the method but outside of the while loop which states if x != 0 (if x never gets to 0 because the condition for the while statement would be False,) then print("the list is not consecutive.") and return

```
def is_consecutive(a_list):
    x = len(a_list)
    while a_list[x] - a_list[x-1] == 1:
        if x == 0:
            print("The list is consecutive.")
            return
        else:
            x -= 1
        
    print("The list is not consecutive.")
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

By comparing a the given list with a reference one of same size and with consecutive terms

```
def is_consecutive(lst):
    if lst == list(range(min(lst), min(lst)+len(lst))):
        print("The list is consecutive.")
    else:
        print("The list is not consecutive.")

is_consecutive(list(range(3, 8)))
#The list is consecutive.
is_consecutive(list(range(3, 9))+list(range(1, 2)))
#The list is not consecutive.
```

Comment: This will say that [5,1,18,2] is consecutive

Comment: Uhhh thanks for comment, I am on it!

Comment: I think it cannot be done via a comparison of series due to the quadratic nature of the arithmetic sum

Comment: ...but  the difference between the min & max should be equal to the size of the list (partially useful)